# What is the probability that the gambler is ruined$?$

Tags: probability

A gambler has one rupee in his pocket.He tosses an unbiased normal coin unless either he is ruined or unless the coin has been tossed for a maximum of five times.If for each head he wins a rupee and for each tail he looses a rupee,then what is the probability that the gambler is ruined$?$

I made the sample space $S=\left\{H,T,HH,HT,HHH,HHT,HTH,HTT,HHHH,HHTH,HHHT,HHTT,HTHH,HTHT,HHHHH,HHHHT,HHTHH,HHHTH,HHHTT,HHTHT,HHTTH,HHTTT,HTHHH,HTHHT,HTHTH,HTHTT\right\}$

Now the cases when he is ruined are $T,HHTTT,HTT,HTHTT$
So i calculated probability that the gambler is ruined=$\frac{4}{26}$.But the book answer is $\frac{22}{32}$

What is wrong in my solution.What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your book's answer is correct.  Your sample space does not consist of 26 equally likely outcomes.

Comment: The probability of $T$ is already $1/2$, so you did not compute correctly. Your 4 possibilities have prob. $1/2$, $1/32$, $1/8$, $1/32$, which will add up to the right thing.

Comment: Additionally, the probability of, say, H, or HH, or HHT, is zero, since you know he doesn't stop there. Those elements shouldn't be in your sample space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your outcomes will never happen.  He can't get a H and then quit, nor would he quit after HTH, etc.  And your samples are not all equally likely to happen.  HHHTH for example will occur only 1 in 32 times, whereas HTT will occur 1 in 8 times, etc.

consider the ways he can be ruined and calculate those probabilities.

T  has a 1/2 probability.
HHTTT has a 1/32 prob,HTT has a 1/8 and HTHTT has 1 1/32.  The probability is
1/2 + 1/32 + 1/8 + 1/32 is 22/32.

Comment: To view all 32 options:

Txxxx: ruin 1/2 

H:
HTTxx ruin 1/8

Comment: I understood,there is a little typo in your answer,probability of HTHTT is 1/32,you wrote 11/32.Anyways,thank you.

Comment: To view all 32 options:

HHHHH
HHHHT
HHHTH
HHHTT
HHTHH
HHTHT
HHTTH
HHTTT ruin 1/32
HTHHH
HTHHT
HTHTH
HTHTT ruin 1/32
HTTxx  ruin 4/32 or 1/8 
Txxxxx  ruin 16/32 or 1/2.

Note there 10 options that do *not* lead to ruin and 22 that do and a total of 32 = 2^5 options.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of your sample space are not equally probable. The gambler has a 50% chance of being ruined in the first toss, but you counted it as being 1 case out 26 equally likely. One way of getting around this is to assume the gambler tosses the coin 5 times always, with any tosses after ruination having no effect. This way, all 32 outcomes are equally probable. If you count the ones that leading to ruin, you should find 22 of them.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is $\frac {11}{16}$...the ways to be ruined are

> $$T,HTT,HHTTT,HTHTT$$

their respective probabilities are

> $$\frac 1 2, \frac 1 8, \frac {1}{32}, \frac {1}{32}$$

and the sum of these probabilities gives answer $\frac {11}{16}$.

Comment: Why downvote this perfect answer? +1 from my side!